# Windows Phone 7 web service

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new in Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 app development. I need to create a web service to connect my phone with db in another place. How can I make it can you advice me with example and can I you digital certificate in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

Andy Pennell [wrote a walkthough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/09/20/using-wcf-on-windows-phone-7-walk-through.aspx) on how to use WCF with Windows Phone.